# Options when data does not fit in memory in R

Tags: r, sparkr, sparklyr

I have 10 csv files, each 2 GB in size. I know if I combine the files there will be 48 milion rows because I have made the query in sql myself. 
My computer has 16 GB of RAM.
What are my options in working with these files in R? 
I understand that I can use sparkr or sparlyr, but I am still trying to understand the technology. Are there any other options?

Comment: There are various methods to work with files stored on disc. See the HPC task view on CRAN for details.

Comment: It partly depends on what you want to do. If your algorithms are easy to parallelize you can just iterate over the 10 files you have now without ever combining theme.

Comment: Although you can process the data in Spark, try with a simple approach first by using `fread` of `data.table`. Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes